# Short program error. New to C++, Adafruit LED strip, Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to write a program that will display a specific light sequence on an Adafruit 60 LED lightstrip. The goal is that I will manually enter a DNA sequence in the code and when the program runs, each base will have its own color displayed on the strip. Here is the code so far:

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#define PIN 1
#define LEDS 60
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LEDS, PIN);

void setup() {
  strip.begin();
  strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'

}
void loop() {

  int i;

  String strand = "CATGCATCGATCATCATCGCATGCGACTCTATGATCAGGAATCTAATCATGCATCGATCATCATCGCGACTGCGCTAGTACT";   //USE CHARAT IN C++



for (i = 0; i < strand.length(); i++) {     

  if (strand[i] == 'G') {               
    colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 0, 0), 50); // Red  
  }                 

  if (strand[i] == 'T') {               
    colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 255, 0), 50); // Green
  }

  if (strand[i] == 'C') {               
    colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 255), 50); // Blue
  }

  if (strand[i] == 'A') {               
    colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 255, 0);    // Yellow
  }
  else {
    colorWipe(strip Color(128, 0, 128);    // Pink
  }


  }
}
```

I'm receiving an error that states

exit status 1
'colorWipe' was not declared in this scope

Would anyone mind helping me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what is `colorWipe` supposed to be? Is it a function in `Adafruit_NeoPixel.h`? Perhaps it belongs in some namespace?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is.

You seem to be expecting that `colorWipe()` is a function that is declared in Adafruit_NeoPixel.h. It isn't.

Possibly, you partially copied your first program from [this example program](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NeoPixel/blob/master/examples/strandtest/strandtest.ino), but forgot to copy the implementation of `colorWipe()` from that source.

I think, though, that colorWipe() is not the effect you're looking for if you want more than one color displayed on the LED strip.

Comment: You're right about me copying parts of the code from strandtest! Thanks for your input and help!